# Pure CSS popup WITHOUT Javascript on DropDownList Change

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, popup

I have users whose group policies block Javascript; so any use of that is out of the question.

I have found a page that performs the function that I need:
[Pure CSS Popup Box](https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO)

However, the popup is triggered after an anchor is clicked.

My issue issue is that I want the popup to trigger on the event change in an asp:DropDownList.  My intent is that if an item is not listed in the DDL, then the user will be able to select the first item "Not Listed".  After this selection I need to have the popup open with elements that will allow them to add the items to the database which populates the DDL.

I have attempted to use the following in the DDL OnSelectedIndexChanged event:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString() + "#popup1");
```

This idea has failed.  I believe it is because I have it inside an Update Panel.  The setup is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<!-- Main Wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper-style2">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- breadcrumbs -->
        <br />
        <div class="row 200%">
            <div class="12u">
                <!-- Content -->
                <div id="maincontent" runat="server">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upInputarea" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updateProgress">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <%-- Equipment Data --%>
                            <section class="box post">
                                <h3 class="bold">Equipment Data</h3>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEquipmentData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updateProgress">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <div id="EquipmentDataDiv2" runat="server" style="float: left; border-left: 2px solid rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25); margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                                            <asp:Panel ID="Pnl1" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                                <span>Model:</span>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEquipmentDataModel" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="round-corners " DataSourceID="SqlModel" DataTextField="Model" DataValueField="ID" />
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="Pnl2" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                                <span>Item:</span>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEquipmentDataItem" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="round-corners width1" DataSourceID="SqlItem" DataTextField="Component" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="Pnl5" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                                <span>S/N:</span>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEquipmentDataSN" runat="server" CssClass="round-corners " />
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                        </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </section>

                            <%-- Submit Button --%>
                            <section class="box post">
                                <div class="inputSet">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSubmit" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updateProgress">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSubmit" runat="server" class="button icon fa-info-sign" Style="cursor: pointer;" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Submit" />
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                            </section>


                            <div id="popup1" runat="server" class="overlay">
                                <div class="css_popup">
                                    <h2>Add Component to Database</h2>
                                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel13" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                            <span>Item:</span>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewItem" runat="server" CssClass="round-corners " />
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel14" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                            <span>NSN:</span>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewNSN" runat="server" CssClass="round-corners " />
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel15" runat="server" CssClass="inputSet2">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddItem" runat="server" class="button icon fa-info-sign" Style="cursor: pointer;" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Add Item" />
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
            <div class="fancybox-loading">
                <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="margin-top: -22px; margin-left: -22px; position: fixed; top: 51%; left: 51%; background: url('/fancybox/fancybox_sprite2.png'); background-position: 2 -2px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

The CSS for these elements mirror that of the link provided above.

Comment: What sort of failure behavior are you seeing?

Comment: While I am using the Redirect to add the Modal target to the URL, the Update Panel (which is a spinning icon) just spins nonstop.  The popup DIV does not display.

Comment: Do you need to use the UpdateProgress control?

Comment: I do, but it is not critical that the popup div be inside the UP

Comment: It's actually not the popup div that's causing the issue. Rather it is from calling a Response.Redirect from within an UpdatePanel. The "request" made from the drop down is never finished, because the page reloads. So the UpdateProgress control sits there waiting for something to tell it to close.

Comment: Also, if you are not seeing the popup div at all, you might need to change it to `Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString() + "#ContentPlaceHolder1_popup1");` But that still doesn't solve the UpdateProgress window not closing.